# Click function runs on load; Uncaught TypError for undefined function

Tags: javascript, object

This is a simple script that should make your text change color if you click on it. However, when I load the page, the color changes automatically (bypassing the click event) and console gives this error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line

```
allP.addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething(), false);
```

My questions are:
1) How can I make this very simple script work?
2) Any other feedback on coding better moving forward? I really appreciate any teaching points.

Markup:

```
<P>Lorem</P>
<P>Lorem</P>
```

Javascript:

```
var colorChanger = {
    init : function() {
        this.clickEvent();
    },

    config : {
        myColor: "red"

    },

    clickEvent : function() {
        allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        allP.addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething(), false);

    },

    changeSomething: function(myColor) {
        myColor = this.config.myColor;

        $("p").css({
            color: myColor // I know changing CSS in JS is bad practice but this is just for the sake of the exercise

        })

    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
colorChanger.init();
});
```

Any feedback is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

1) `addEventListener` expects a function as second argument but you're passing what the function returns (that is `undefined`).

2) In `this.changeSomething`, the context (`this`) is `window`, because that's the context of functions called on events.

Change

```
allP.addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething(), false);
```

to

```
allP.addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething.bind(this), false);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also, this...

```
allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
allP.addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething(), false);
```

..won't work. You can't just access the items in the nodeList like that.

Try something like this:

```
allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for (var i=0; i<allP.length; i++) {
    allP.item(i).addEventListener("click", this.changeSomething.bind(this), false);
}
```

Comment: @phil_C @dystroy - Also, although I'm not sure, I don't think this `allP=document.querySelectorAll("p"); allP.addEventListener(...` will work. [Check this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll). I don't think you can just use the nodeList to add eventlisteners to every item in that list. But I could be wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @myfunkyside you're right. You should update the answer (it's CW for a reason... well... two reasons but including this one...)